# Can an excel datasource in WSO2 data service take a variable name for the excelURL

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

The following is the excel data source definition in my wso2 data service.

Is there a way to define a property in a proxy and use that as the excel Url in the excel data source of the data service ?

In other words, I need the excel file to be dynamically determined.

The following is the data source definition in the data service

```
<config id="OrganisationImportDataSource">
      <property name="excel_datasource">C:/Organisations.xls</property>
</config>
```

Instead of this, is it possible to use something like the below

```
  <config id="OrganisationImportDataSource">
     <property name="excel_datasource">get-property('fileName', 'default')
     </property>
  </config> where fileName is a property defined in a calling proxy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The excel data source is validated at wso2 startup. Thus what I was trying like above does not work. 

We re-aligned our requirement to the limitation that excel data source need to be pre-defined and redefined our requirement to ensure tenant specificity of excel data source. For this, we uploaded the excel in a specific location within configuration / goverance registry. This is tenant specific even if we have the same name for excel data source. 
So the following configuration is tenant specific

```
<config id="OrganisationImportDataSource">
      <property name="excel_datasource">conf:/repository/Organisations.xls</property>
   </config>
```